# How to run a jnlp app on 15.10

Tags: firefox, java, openjdk

I have trouble running a java app starting with java WebStart.

I do have `icedtea-netx` installed (1.5.3-0ubuntu0.15.10.1), but when I try to run the app, I get the following error:

> +(CONNECTED DOWNLOADED STARTED) Status: CONNECTED DOWNLOADED STARTED
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java/net/URLPermission     at
>        java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)     at
>        java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)     at
>        net.sourceforge.jnlp.SecurityDesc.(SecurityDesc.java:164)
>        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.(JNLPFile.java:137)     at 
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.(JNLPFile.java:213)     at
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.(JNLPFile.java:198)     at
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.(JNLPFile.java:184)     at
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.fromUrl(Launcher.java:447)     at
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:279)     at
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:258)     at
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:59)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     at
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:225)
>   Exception while reflectively finding URLPermission - host is probably not running Java
>   8+ JNLP file location: digdash.jnlp Read 320 entries from Firefox's
>   preferences Found preferences file:
>   /home/franck/.mozilla/firefox/7qd3jlf3.default/prefs.js Using
>   firefox's profiles file: /home/franck/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
>   Starting security dialog thread WARNING: key
>   deployment.system.cachedir has no value, setting to default value No
>   User level deployment.properties found. java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/franck/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties (Aucun fichier
>   ou dossier de ce type)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native> Method)     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)     at
>   java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:72)     at
>   net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.parsePropertiesFile(DeploymentConfiguration.java:655)
>       at 
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.findSystemConfigFile(DeploymentConfiguration.java:479)
>       at 
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.load(DeploymentConfiguration.java:292)
>       at 
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.load(DeploymentConfiguration.java:262)
>       at 
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPRuntime$DeploymentConfigurationHolder.initConfiguration(JNLPRuntime.java:451)
>       at 
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPRuntime$DeploymentConfigurationHolder.(JNLPRuntime.java:446)
>       at 
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPRuntime.getConfiguration(JNLPRuntime.java:481)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DirectoryValidator.(DirectoryValidator.java:224)
>       at 
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.move14AndOlderFilesTo15Structure(DeploymentConfiguration.java:829)
>       at 
> net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.move14AndOlderFilesTo15StructureCatched(DeploymentConfiguration.java:733)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:154)
>   cache: /home/franck/.cache/icedtea-web file exists:true
>   config:/home/franck/.config/icedtea-web file exists: true
>   System is already following XDG .cache and .config specifications

Main error seems to be : `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/franck/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties`. (touching the file does not do the trick...)

I came accross this bug report https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/36082 which might be related... So here is my question: what is the current situation of jnlp on 15.10 ? Is it supposed to just work or is it broken somehow ? Is my problem specific to my install or related to IcedTea on 15.10 ?

And... does anyone think of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm answering my own question: the problem was with the jnlp file format itself, and I had the parsing error I overlooked.

It had to do the the format of the href attribute of the jnlp tag containing some question marks (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112318/the-reference-to-entity-subset-must-end-with-the-delimiter)